# Slider : How to set the position of the " input box" on the right?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

How can I change the positionof ".ui-slider-input" in the css file ?.....

Example, in jquery mobile CSS

```
input.ui-slider-input,
.ui-field-contain input.ui-slider-input { display: inline-block;  width: 50px; position:   relative; }
```

i've tried a lot at :

http://jsfiddle.net/EWQ6n/26/

Many thanks....

Comment: please be more descriptive. let us know what are you trying to achieve, what have you tried so far, and ask a concrete question. you may want to read the [FAQ entry on how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: Fine question man! I really dont see any issues with the question + jsfiddle is good :) Good one for a starter but please read FAQ for further reference. Have a nice one, CHeerios!

Comment: Please don't just post links to jsfiddle, copy the code into your question and *then* post a link to a jsfiddle. Since questions on SO has to have value for future visitors, one criteria is that the question can be searchable, if you don't copy the content into your question, it won't be, and thus closed as too-localized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's ok with float: 'right',thank to Bill !

For example in jquery mobile,

jquerymobile.css, line 2037 :

```
input.ui-slider-input, .ui-field-contain input.ui-slider-input { display: inline- block;**float: right;** width: 50px; position: relative; }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to swap them is to float the input box to the right. You'll probably need to adjust other properties to get it to look how you want it to.

```
$('input[name="slider"]').css('float', 'right');
```

Comment: `$(".ui-slider-input").val(30)`

Comment: That works too since the slider is an actual input element. I prefer 'attr' since it works on any element and any attribute, probably not as good performance wise but one less thing to remember.

Comment: If you look at the OP's code they are not trying to change the `value` attribute of something. They are trying to change how an element is displayed (basically trying to alter the element's CSS).

Comment: yes, excuse me because i'm not precise;
i 'd like to postion the input box on the right ....

is there a way in the css propretis like 'align right' or position : 'right ?

Comment: Thank you @Bill, you are right ! _$(".ui-slider-input").wrap($('<div />').css({ position : 'float', float: 'right', display : 'inline-block', height : '36px', width : '65px', overflow : 'hidden' })); _ http://jsfiddle.net/EWQ6n/35 – Paolo 7 mins ago

Comment: I don't see a reason to do this with JavaScript though. Why not just set a CSS rule? `.ui-mobile .ui-page .ui-content .ui-slider-input { float : right }`. Using JavaScript to apply inline-CSS is a bit of an anti-pattern. Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EWQ6n/40/. If you only want to do this to a single element or a specific group of elements, give them a shared class and add that class to the CSS rule.